# Does partitioning improve performance if all partitions are equally used?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

Consider the following situation:

- I have a large PostgreSQL table with a primary key of type `UUID`. The UUIDs are generated randomly and spread uniformly across the UUID space.
- I partition the table on this UUID column on 256 ranges (e.g. based on the first 8 bits of the UUID).
- All partitions are stored on the same physical disk.

Basically this means all the 256 partitions will be equally used (unlike with time-based paritionning where the most recent parititon would normally be hotter than the other ones).

Will I see *any* performance improvement at all by doing this type of partitioning:

1. For queries based on the UUID, returning a single row (`WHERE uuid_key = :id`)?
2. For other queries that must search all partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most queries will become slower. For example, if you search by `uuid_key`, the optimizer has to determine which partition to search, something that grows in expense with the number of partitions. The index scan itself will not be notably faster on a small table than on a big table.

You could benefit if you have several tables partitioned alike and you join them on the partitioning key, so that you get a *partitionwise join* (but remember to set `enable_partitionwise_join = on`).  There are similar speed gains for *partitionwise aggregates*.

Even though you cannot expect a performance gain for your query, partitioning may still have its use, for example if you need several autovacuum workers to process a single table.

Answer (score 0):

> Will I see any performance improvement at all by doing this type of
> partitioning:
>
> ```
> For queries based on the UUID, returning a single row (WHERE uuid_key = :id)?
> ```

Yes: Postgresql will search only in the right partition. Also you can gain performances in insert or update, reducing page contention.

> 2. For other queries that must search all partitions?

Not really, but index desing can minimize the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first part? Without partitioning, Postgres will also only search the relevant branch of the B-Tree index. Any why does it reduce page contention? UUIDs are random so you're unlikely to get page contention in the first place even without partitioning.